# Variable with '-' (minus signals) in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

This is so simple yet...

```
FOLDER='/home/user/.ssh'
SSH="$FOLDER/local-rsync-key.pub"
if [ -f "$SSH" ]; then
...
```

It looks that Bash considers the '-' as a minus signal and the IF statement always fails... How can I write this variable the right way?

UPDATE:
This is another real example:

I am tring to rename files with "-" in front of the filename, for example: "-0001.jpg"

However, everyime I try to run:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i//-/}"; done
```

or:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i#*-}"; done
```

I got this error:

```
mv: invalid option -- '0'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Thanks for any light!

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557985/mv-invalid-option-0) quetion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use "--" (indicating no more options) after "mv" or "./" before the name of the file (indicating it is about a file). For example:

```
for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "${i#*-}"; done
```

or:

```
for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "./${i#*-}"; done
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this works for pretty much any Linux tool ever. `find` is one notable exception.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have a `$` in front of your `SSH` *assignment,* that's only needed when you're *using* the variable. Without that, it works fine, as in the following transcript:

```
pax> touch abc-xyz

pax> ll a*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax paxgrp 0 2011-06-24 05:15 abc-xyz

pax> FOLDER=.

pax> $SSH="$FOLDER/abc-xyz"
bash: =./abc-xyz: No such file or directory

pax> SSH="$FOLDER/abc-xyz"

pax> if [ -f "$SSH" ]
...> then
...>     echo yes
...> fi
yes

pax> _
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash syntax, when you *set* a variable just use the variable name:

```
VAR=value
```

When you *reference* the variable, use the `$` prefix:

```
echo $VAR
```

Your code has a stray dollar sign prefix where you are trying to set the SSH variable. The dashes inside the variable should be no problem.