# mv: invalid option -- '0'

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, mv, batch-rename

How can I rename files with "-" in front of the filename, for example: "-0001.jpg"

Everyime I try to run:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i//-/}"; done
```

or:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i#*-}"; done
```

I got this error:

```
mv: invalid option -- '0'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Thanks for any light!

Comment: I answered but I suppose this question appears already, since it's so a common fact

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And, for the reccords, I tried to find some answer before making the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
mv ./-00008.jpg to/some/where.jpg
   ^ - start with path...
```

Comment: While many programs support `--`, this solution will work for absolutely all programs.

Comment: yeap, I am a bit GNU biased since when I had to use non-GNU "common" tools (mv, find, one of non-GNU awk...) on e.g. Solaris, I realized that I missed a lot  GNU "extension" and "enhancement".

Comment: (no `mv "-hey" dest` wont work, I think since the "" are used before to split arguments into argv array properly, but once placed there, there's no way to know if there where "" or not)

Answer (score 13):

As with most GNU commands, use the `--` switch before the filename with the hyphen. It signifies "end of switches".

```
mv OPTIONS -- -file_with_hyphen.txt dest.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

Put a double - before the arguments that can contain "-" in the begin; then there can't be options after --.

```
mv OPTIONS -- ...
```